# WordPress is creating nonce as a logged in user but verifying it incorrectly

Tags: ajax, wordpress, nonce, wp-api

I'm having trouble validating a nonce created with `wp_create_nonce()` inside a hidden input with the name *nonce* in an html form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce('action_name'); ?>" />
```

The form submission is done via ajax and validated with `check_ajax_referer('action_name','nonce')`. This always returns `-1`. All REST endpoints have been tested without nonces and work 100% fine.

### The issue seems to stem from wp's user identifcation.

**My debugging so far**

*Nonce creation*
Within *wp-includes/pluggable.php* `wp_create_nonce('action_name')` creates a nonce hashing various variables including the user id and the action.

*Ajax call*
I submit an ajax call which calls `check_ajax_referer('action_name','nonce')`. This in turn calls `wp_verify_nonce($nonce,$action)` which verifies the nonce by hashing the same variables and comparing the two.

*Reverse engineering to locate problem*
My problem is that `wp_create_nonce('action_name')` is being created with the correct user id. However, when I run `check_ajax_referer('action_name','nonce')` which calls `wp_verify_nonce($nonce,$action)` which in turn calls `wp_get_current_user()`; no user is found (user id is 0).

**Evidence the problem is to do with user id**

If I temporarily edit *wp-includes/pluggable.php* to force my user id, the nonce validation works fine. It's as if ajax requests to a known and valid endpoint are being treated as if the user is logged out regardless of whether they are or not.

I'm clearly missing something here, but I have no idea what.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network ie wordpress. Unfortunately, the "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" doesn't give the wordpress community as an option.

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: @TyKroll see answer below. I created this question in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com (/questions/375099/wordpress-is-creating-nonce-as-a-logged-in-user-but-verifying-it-incorrectly/375172#375172 ) and tried to close this one.

Comment: any luck finding the solution ? I have the same issue.

Comment: @AravindEmmadishetty I added the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because a separate nonce with the action **wp_rest** is not being sent by the server to the client and received back from the client in an HTTP request header called **X-WP-Nonce** with every REST request.

To get this working, you will have to generate a nonce like this:

```
wp_create_nonce('wp_rest')
```

...and provide it to the client making the rest call. Once your client has the nonce value, you need to add it to every REST request e.g.:

```
headers: {
    'X-WP-Nonce': nonce,
}
```

Creating the nonce on the server and accessing it on the client can be done several ways. Using `wp_localize_script()` is the most common and probably best practice for WordPress. `wp_localize_script()` addds a global variable to the client for a script to access. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/.